For count reverse pairs question why will this slightly modified logic from count inversion pairs won't work?
This is my code for counting inverrsion pair i have modified the logic from counting inversion pairs but it is not working could you please point out why?
int cnt = 0;

void merge(vector<int> &a, int low, int mid, int high) {
  vector<int> temp;
  int left = low;
  int right = mid + 1;
  while (left <= mid && right <= high) {
    if (a[left] <= a[right]) {
      temp.push_back(a[left]);
      left++;
    } else {
      if (a[left] > 2 * a[right] && left <right) {
        cnt += mid - left + 1;
      }
      temp.push_back(a[right]);
      right++;
    }
  }

  while (left <= mid) {
    temp.push_back(a[left]);
    left++;
  }
  while (right <= high) {
    temp.push_back(a[right]);
    right++;
  }

  for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    a[i] = temp[i - low];
  }
  for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << cnt << endl;
}

void mergesort(vector<int> &a, int low, int high) {
  if (low >= high)
    return;
  int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
  mergesort(a, low, mid);
  mergesort(a, mid + 1, high);
  merge(a, low, mid, high);
}

int team(vector<int> &a, int n) {
  mergesort(a, 0, n - 1);
  return cnt;
}

why is this not working the answer for the testcase 4 1 2 3 1 is 3 is am getting 2 in this code ?

What is the reasoning you have for doing 2 * a[right]?

the question is to find a[i] > a[j] where i<j i have updated the code of finding inversion parirs to suit this question

Sorry, but could you explain why you have 2 * a[right]? I don't see how your comment answers my enquiry.

Hi. Could you please [edit] your question to include the relevant #include <...> and using namespace ...; so that we can run your code?

There are two problems with the code:
First, you don't really need if (a[left] > 2 * a[right] && left <right) condition at all. a[left] > 2 * a[right] seems strange since you need to know of all cases where a[left] is > or < than a[right] and this is already managed by the if before. Having values twice smaller or larger should not matter here. Second condition, left <right is automatically true always. Notice how left can only be as big as mid, and right starts at mid+1.
Secondly, this algorithm looks at the problem in reverse from what you think. When you expect the answer 3, it means you want to vector sorted as 4 3 2 1 1; however here you put smallest values first, so it sorts values as 1 1 2 3 4 instead. So it's not 3, it's actually 6 inversions here.
If you want it to count inversions the other direction, you need to inverse your comparison too:
if (a[left] >= a[right]) {

is the right test.
Here's the final sorting:
while (left <= mid && right <= high) {
    if (a[left] >= a[right]) {
      temp.push_back(a[left]);
      left++;
    } else {
      cnt += mid - left + 1;
      temp.push_back(a[right]);
      right++;
    }
  }

if you want to get 3 as a return.
